# HTML above flash without wmode?

Tags: html, flash

Could someone settle this little dispute please.

If I set wmode=transparent on the flash template everything works magically. However, the flash developer says that by doing this the template will be slowed down significantly..

So the questions.

1) How much of an impact does wmode have on performance today?

2) Is there any other way to place HTML on top of flash?

It should be noted the HTML only appears on top of the flash when they click on a video -> rare. The flash only is animated again after the video is closed and the user clicks on a rollover or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bunch of websites with transparent flash objects and heavy animations, etc.. I've never noticed any change. I think it should only matter if you had issues with performance to start with (zillions of vectors being animated or something).

Comment: One thing though is that the dimensions of a flash object have a massive impact on performance. That's the only thing I'm normally concerned about.

Comment: So wmode=transparent on a full screen flash template = bad? Is opaque any better? Is there any other way to get HTML on top of the flash template.

Comment: Yeah I'd say for a full-screener that it wouldn't end well. But hey what stops you from just trying it out and seeing if it works fine? I reckon it should be alright.

Comment: That is what I have done. I have done it on the quiet. If someone complains I will try opaque :)